# Prefill an item on Google Form without using "Prefill URL"

Tags: google-forms, autofill

Is it possible to prefill items in Google Form without using prefill urls but directly with Google Script?

Every question I searched is related to prefill url.

Example:
I need to create a progressive number for responses and I need it as a form item (to use it with Form Publisher).

So the first time a user open the form he/she will compile it leaving the "progressive number" item empty.

On submit the progressive number will be generated with something like:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var row =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();

sheet.getRange(row,7).setValue(row-1);
}
```

Now the problem is... how to prefill the progressive number's dedicated item in case a user will edit the response?

Comment: No, it's not possible.  You would need to build a Web App.

Comment: Thank you @SandyGood. I did more search about it and I confirm it. The only way is a Web App.